# Java network application run as service losing network connection

Tags: java, service, websocket, raspberry-pi3

Well as in title. I have Java network application which is running on raspberry pi 3. When i run application from console like **java -jar myApp.java** or **sudo nohup java -jar myApp.java** and then i leave this it works fine for many hours.

Then I tried run this application as a service. After configure wlan auto, and run systmd script and all stuff. Application is starting properly, but after few seconds it's losing network connection. I can add that there is wifi connection. I was wandering whats the difference between application run manually and run as service and i did't find anything specific. Is there something i should know about? As far i did't find solution.

I've tired many combinations of systemd scripts but nothing solves my problem. And I also tried to run this app from another on raspberry, but it works like running from this service.

Now i can add that, when i hit from console **systemctl stop myService** and then **systemctl start myService** it also works fine.

```
systemd script below:

[Unit]
Description = Java Service
After network.target = MyService.service

[Service]
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/MyService.sh start
ExecStop = /usr/local/bin/MyService.sh stop
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/MyService.sh reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Bash script to run the service:

 #!/bin/bash

SERVICE_NAME=app

PATH_TO_JAR=/home/user/app.jar

RE='^[0-9]+$'

APP_PID=\`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "app.jar" | awk '{print $2}'\`

case $1 in

    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if ! [[ $APP_PID =~ $RE ]]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null & 
            APP_PID=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "app.jar" | awk '{print $2}'`

            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;

    stop)
        if [[ $APP_PID =~ $RE ]]; then
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..." &
            kill $APP_PID &
            APP_PID="" &
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;

    restart)
        if [[ $APP_PID =~ $RE ]]; then
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $APP_PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> >> /dev/null & 
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SE`enter code here`RVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I don't know exactly what is the reason, but when i give sleep before run this application it works properly. When I start application after this this time, after which it was losing connetion it work fine.